# Canvas grid random generation not generating

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas, paint

Hi everyone i'm attempting to generate a grid in android studio for the floodit game as part of my assignment. The grid genereated should be random each time so i'm using a switch statement to and paint to generate the colours as shown below.

```
 Paint paint1 = new Paint  (getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
        Paint paint2 = new Paint (getResources().getColor(R.color.color2));
        Paint paint3 = new Paint (getResources().getColor(R.color.color3));
        Paint paint4 = new Paint (getResources().getColor(R.color.color4));
        Paint paint5 = new Paint (getResources().getColor(R.color.color5));
        Paint paint6 = new Paint (getResources().getColor(R.color.color6));


        for (int col = 0; col < mGame.getHeight(); col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < mGame.getWidth(); row++) {
                Random random = new Random(6);
                int num = 1;
                int randomResult = random.nextInt();

                float cx = separator + (diameterx + separator) * col + diameterx / 2;
                float cy = separator + (diametery + separator) * row + diametery / 2;
                canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth, availableHeight, paint6);
                switch (randomResult) {
                    case 0:
                        canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth/2, availableHeight/2, paint1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth, availableHeight, paint2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth, availableHeight, paint3);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth, availableHeight, paint4);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth, availableHeight, paint5);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth, availableHeight, paint6);
                        break;

                }


            }
        }
```

The issue is the code within the switch statement does not work while (for demonstration sake) the  `canvas.drawRect(cx, cy, availableWidth, availableHeight, paint6);`just above the switch statement seems to work fine so it's some issue within that block that i'm failing to understand. Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to set for all paints:

```
paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but it unfortunately did not do anything.

Comment: Are you sure, that `cx`, `cy`,  `availableWidth` and `availableHeight` have a correct values?

Comment: Also you have incorrect using Random class.
Try:
`Random random = new Random();
int randomResult = random.nextInt(6);`

Comment: Also you have incorrect using Paint class. `int` value int Paint constructor is not a color, it's a flag. Use:
`Paint paint = new Paint(); paint.setColor(0xFF000000);`